# Windows Phone 8 tile doesn't show correct image

Tags: windows-phone-8

Does anyone know why my Win Phone 8 app tile doesn't show the icon I set? This is what I get (and yes, am am sure that's not my app's icon):

[image]

This is what I have so far and I ran out of ideas of what can be wrong:

- The small icon is a png of 110x110
- The medium icon is a png of 202x202
- Both images have the build Type = Content
- Both images have the copy to output property = Copy if newer
- The application icon is the same as the small icon and it shows alright in the program list.

Here is a part of my app's manifest:

```
 <TemplateIconic>
      <SmallImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Icons\AppIcon_small.png</SmallImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>
      <IconImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Icons\AppIcon_medium.png</IconImageURI>
      <Title>
      </Title>
      <Message>
      </Message>
      <BackgroundColor>
      </BackgroundColor>
      <HasLarge>false</HasLarge>
      <LargeContent1>
      </LargeContent1>
      <LargeContent2>
      </LargeContent2>
      <LargeContent3>
      </LargeContent3>
      <DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">
      </DeviceLockImageURI>
    </TemplateIconic>
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this? If so how?

Answer (score 6):

If you use TemplateIconic tile the images need to be transparent icons as outlined in [Iconic Tile template for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) because it is just going to end up being a white icon inside a tile. Your image appears as a white square because it does not have any transparency. With the images you have, you would want to use the TemplateFlip tiles and adjust the size of your tiles accordingly.

Comment: I think this is where someone says, "The least expensive way to add transparency is to [download Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/), use the magic wand, select the background, and hit `delete` to make each magic wand selection transparent when saved to png." You can also do that in the GIMP or Photoshop, etc, of course, but apparently not MSPaint.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
After a lot of brainstorming I tried this and woah it worked!

Check if the image you are setting has a white (or other) background color. If it has, remove the background from the image using Photoshop(Tool: magic eraser) and keep the background transparent.

Replace this transparent background image and it will show up in emulator!

Hope this works at ur end too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the manifest file? You can choose the images in that file. I mean using the UI in the studio, open the manifest file and choose the image.

Comment: Yes, I tried both selecting the image from UI and editing the manifest manually.

Answer (score 0):

According to Iconic Tile sizing info in [Iconic Tile template for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), both small icon and medium icon must be design with transparent background.

- The small icon is a png of 70x110
- The medium icon is a png of 130x202

If you need to set the background color, set the BackgroundColor in WMAppManifest.xml as follow.

```
<BackgroundColor>[hex ARGB format color]</BackgroundColor>
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with **Xamarin.Forms (Shared)** for my WP-app and also had problems to implement the Tile in the WP-part of my project. 
To set the background to **transparent** to the tile image have done the job. 
But I have used images with 158x158 and 336x336 what also works and allows to use the standard-icon (in a higher resolution) what - I think - most users want to do. 
I have created a short description for all visitors, who use XF for WP-development (including app-icon, splash-screen and Tile).

[How to add app-icon, splash-screen and Tile in a WP 8.0 XF-project](http://www.matrixguide.ch/datenablage/diverses/Add_SplashScreen_Tiles_to_WP80_Project.pdf)